# Getting RequestTimeout from S3 when uploading to a presigned URL

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

For small files, say < 5Mb, uploading to S3 via a presigned URL is working fine. When I try to upload anything larger than this then, I seem to get `400 Bad Request` responses from S3 with `RequestTimeout` as the error.

I'm able to recreate this using curl:

```
# Create a test file:
mkfile -n 20m ./testfile

# Get the presigned URL
curl -XPOST http://localhost:3000/uploads -d "filename=testdata"

# Upload to S3
curl -H "Content-Type: binary/octet-stream" -XPUT -vvv -T testfile "<Presigned URL>"
```

Signing code looks like this:

```
@presigned_url ||= Aws::S3::Presigner.new.presigned_url(
  :put_object,
  bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
  key: key,
  acl: 'private',
  expires_in: 3600,
  content_type: 'binary/octet-stream'
)
```

Note that this all works fine for files < 5Mb, with more frequent failures occurring as the file size increases. Has anyone seen these issues and resolved them?

Comment: This sounds like you have connectivity issues... packet loss.  Are you running these tests from inside EC2 or elsewhere on the Internet?

Comment: Elsewhere, though no connection issues for anything else.

Comment: I've tested this from several geographic locations, and found the same problem

Comment: its a server problem, not related to any of the code you've shown here. could be your actual server, could be a proxy, but somewhere there is a max size or max upload time or max connection time rule being violated. can you reproduce it  running `echo ok>ok.txt; php -S 0.0.0.0:9999 ok.txt` on the server and `curl -v -T testfile url:9999` on the client? also i think its a case for serverfault.com , not stackoverflow.com

Comment: @hanshenrik the upload goes directly to s3 from the browser / client / curl. No intermediate server is involved.

Comment: contact the server admins (i guess this means going through s3 customer support?), im pretty sure its their fault

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, that's a paid service. This problem seems too broad to be unique to this situation, so asking here first if anyone else has experienced it

Comment: It can't be S3. I use boto3 to get a pre-signed URL and upload very large zip files to S3 using Javascript with no problem. Maybe you want to try using boto or the cli to verify the problem is not with the SDK. Also have you tried specifying the range for your upload using `content-length-range`?

Comment: S3 will send this error when it does not receive data from the client for 20 seconds. Does using curl with retries resolve the issue? Multi-part upload? Some people have reported similar issues which are resolved with sending headers before the payload using the `100-continue` `Expect` header http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html. Otherwise, it doesn't appear you're hitting any S3 limits.